# can't replace or insert \ before all space in a String

Tags: java

Can't add character "\" before all spaces of string.

`"test string"` should be `"test\ string"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash (it's a special character) -

```
String str = "test string";
str = str.replace(" ", "\\ ");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is (the requested)

```
test\ string
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
"test string".replaceAll(" ","\\\\ ");
```

Comment: The OP wants `\ ` not  ` \\` :P . And yes, in your case, 4 slashes are needed :P

Comment: @TheLostMind:- Updated that!